# Grails 2.3.4 - Error executing script Clean: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1

Tags: eclipse, grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am using `eclipse kepler` and after shutting down my computer and turning it on again I am getting this error message:

```
grails run-app --stacktrace

|Loading Grails 2.3.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.Error
|
Error executing script RunApp: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1 (NOTE: Stac
k trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
        at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.run(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
        at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:32)
        at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy.run(_GrailsClean_groovy:29)
        at _GrailsClean_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy.run(_GrailsWar_groovy:27)
        at _GrailsWar_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.run(_GrailsRun_groovy:28)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
        at RunApp.run(RunApp.groovy:25)
        at RunApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Refl
ectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(Refl
ectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closur
e1
        ... 29 more

Error |
Error executing script RunApp: _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1
```

That is my `BuildConfig` which definitely worked before the restart:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.tet.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
        mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.24'
        runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.47"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.1"
        compile ':cache:1.1.1'

        // Spring Security and UI Plugin
        compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
        compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"

        compile (":postgresql-extensions:0.6.1") {
            excludes "hibernate"
        }

        //Grails Rich UI
        compile ":richui:0.8"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.8"
        runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.1"
        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
    }
}
```

I tried a `grails clean` and `grails compile` and also cleaned the project under eclipse. However I am still getting the error message.

I really appreciate your answer on my problem

Comment: Remove/delete the 'target' or wherever your 'work' folder is and run grails again

Comment: It would be ideal if "grails clean" did that. Just ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This is some error for the lib and plugin in grails to solved this,

Delete the folder

`${Path_Project}\target\work`

En run the commands

`grails clean` and `grails compile`

Comment: This helps me. I cannot understand why this error happens frequently.

Answer (score 24):

Clearing the working directory may not solve this problem always. In my case, I have fixed this issue  by deleting the working directory as well as all the scripts in

```
%HOMEPATH%/.grails/2.3.4/projects/projectName/scriptCache
```

where "2.3.4" is Grails version and projectName denotes the Grails project name.

Comment: Well in my case deleting the project folder from the directory did the job.

Comment: clearing scriptCache is worked for me and I haven't deleted work directory