# ScriptExitException on run-app on particular grails 2.0.4 application

Tags: grails

I have no clue on what the error is about. I see no reference to anything from my application code. No error logs as well. Earlier this application setup was fine. I remember this broke after I made some changes to Java version, by using jEnv.

Now, I am again back to Java version 1.7.0_80, but or the other issue is still there. Following happens when I do `grails> run-app --verbose` while in grails mode -

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.exit(BaseSettingsApi.java:370)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:952)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1131)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at _GrailsCompile.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy:77)
    at _GrailsCompile.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:46)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:952)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1131)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1087)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at _GrailsCompile$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile.groovy:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor120.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor115.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:730)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1150)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at 
    ...
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:263)
| Error Error running script run-app --verbose: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException
```

Comment: Can you show the console output that immediately precedes `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.ScriptExitException`?

Comment: I did some cleanup - followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/22509310/351903, and now I am getting the Unsupported major.minor version 52.0  error. I am running everything on command line. I get java version 1.7 but am still getting this error.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the earlier error now

Comment: "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 error" - Are you running bytecode generated with a Java 8 compiler but running with a pre Java 8 runtime?

Comment: "52.0" is Java 8, and Java 8 is not supported with Grails 2.0.4.  Grails 2.5 is the first version of Grails for which we support Java 8.

Comment: "Cannot reproduce the earlier error now" - Neither can I.

Comment: " Are you running bytecode generated with a Java 8 compiler?" How do I ensure that? I did fresh `clean` and `compile` on my project. getting this error on compile now.

Comment: "How do I ensure that?" - The error message indicates that some bytecode that was compiled with Java 8 is on your classpath.  It is practically impossible to guess what code that is without seeing your project.  It could be your own code, it could be a library that you are pulling into your project.

Comment: I was finally able to resolve this after having a separate local maven repository for this project. I am not sure why it worked, if it was a Java 8 issue earlier, as I am still running with Java 8.

BuildConfig.groovy - 

    mavenLocal("/Users/sandeepan.nath/grails/.m2/repository")
        
run-app worked with Java version 1.8 though. I am yet to try it with 1.7